# What is the correct way to redirect_to in AJAX?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax, jquery

I'm sending info via jQuery AJAX to a post method. Then afterwards I want to redirect to my home page. But `redirect_to root_url` doesn't work in this scenario. What is the correct way to redirect from an ajax post?

**jQuery:**

```
function responseCallbackHandler(response) {
   switch (response.status) {
     case 400:
         console.log(response.error);
         break;
     case 201:
         $.ajax({ url: '#{addbank_bankaccts_path}',
         type: 'POST',
         beforeSend: function(xhr) {xhr.setRequestHeader('X-CSRF-Token', '#{form_authenticity_token}')},
         dataType: "json",
         data: 'account_uri=' + response.data.uri
         });
         break;
     }
 }
```

**controller:**

```
class BankacctsController < ApplicationController
  def addbank
      # some logic here
      redirect_to root_url, :notice => "Back account added!"
  end
end
```

Comment: You can't redirect in an ajax response.  Instead, send something back that the JS code can identify and perform the redirect there.

Comment: might helpfull http://stackoverflow.com/questions/199099/how-to-manage-a-redirect-request-after-a-jquery-ajax-call

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use redirect_to for ajax request. Follow this similar answer at stack overflow, it will solve your problem:

[Is it possible to use redirect_to when it's called by remote ajax?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16093889/is-it-possible-to-use-redirect-to-when-its-called-by-remote-ajax/16098942#16098942)